# Give people a price on my website when they join my facebook network

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I was wondering if it is possible to give people something when they join my network on Facebook.

I am working on an website where people have to buy credits to get certain services. I want to give them 3 free credits when they join the group on Facebook. Is this possible?

I am also new to Facebook, so I don't know what to create. Should I create a personal account for myself, or should I make this for the company?

And how is this network called, is it a fan-club, a group, or something else?

Can someone point me in the right direction.

On a side-note: My application is in late development stage. Can I develop this setup in private mode, or should my website be already up and running? I'm working in PHP/MySQL.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: he is giving credits FOR joining a group, not requiring

Comment: The question is about giving a user credits when they join the group - not charging them.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I've removed my dumb comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check and see if the user is a fan of a page (your page) via their API